# Goldbach theory in C

Tags: c, primes

I want to write some code which takes any positive, even number (greater than 2) and gives me the smallest pair of primes that sum up to this number. 
I need this program to handle any integer up to 9 digits long.

My aim is to make something that looks like this:

> ```
> Please enter a positive even integer ( greater than 2 ) :
> 10
> The first primes adding : 3+7=10.
> Please enter a positive even integer ( greater than 2 ) :
> 160
> The first primes adding : 3+157=160.
> Please enter a positive even integer ( greater than 2 ) :
> 18456
> The first primes adding : 5+18451=18456.
> ```

I don't want to use any library besides stdio.h. I don't want to use arrays, strings, or anything besides for the most basic toolbox: scanf, printf, for, while, do-while, if, else if, break, continue, and the basic operators (<,>, ==, =+, !=, %, *, /, etc...). 
Please no other functions especially is_prime.

I know how to limit the input to my needs so that it loops until given a valid entry.

So now I'm trying to figure out the algorithm.

I thought of starting a while loop like something like this:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
long first, second, sum, goldbach, min;
long a,b,i,k; //indices

int main (){

    while (1){
        printf("Please enter a positive integer :\n");
        scanf("%ld",&goldbach);
        if ((goldbach>2)&&((goldbach%2)==0)) break;
        else printf("Wrong input, ");
        }

    while (sum!=goldbach){
        for (a=3;a<goldbach;a=(a+2))
            for (i=2;(goldbach-a)%i;i++)
                first = a;
        for (b=5;b<goldbach;b=(b+2))
            for (k=2;(goldbach-b)%k;k++)
        sum = first + second;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us any good reasons for such restrictions. Sounds much like homework or other types of rules imposed by a third party.

Comment: Arrays are far more basic than `stdio.h`. Any solution you come up with that neglects arrays will be terribly inefficient.

Comment: @JensGustedt yes I forgot to mention this is part of an exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a function to test primality

```
int is_prime(unsigned long n)
```

And then you only need to test whether `a` and `goldbach - a` are both prime. You can of course assume `a <= goldbach/2`.

And be sure to handle `goldbach = 4` correctly.

If the requirements don't allow defining and using your own functions, ignore them first. Solve the problem using any functions you deem helpful and convenient. When you have a working solution using disallowed functionality, then you start replacing that with allowed constructs. Self-defined functions can be inlined directly, replacing the `return` with an assignment, so instead of `if (is_prime(a))`, you have the code to determine whether `a` is prime and instead of `return`ing the result you assign it `is_prime = result;` and test that variable `if (is_prime)`. Where you have used library functions, reimplement them yourself - efficiency doesn't matter much - and then inline them too.

Comment: hey thanks for the response, however I want to achieve this without the is_prime function

Comment: That's a _very_ odd requirement. Anyway, you need it, be it as a function or in other shape, so just inline what would be the function body.

Comment: A strange requirement indeed.  You could use Eratosthenes to create a list of primes, and search for a pair from the list that add up to the target even number.

Comment: @rossum "I don't want to use arrays, ..." so that's another idea ruled out by strange requirements.

Comment: @DanielFischer "so just inline what would be the function body." can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @nofe you understand `is_prime` isn't a builtin function, right? You'd be writing it yourself.

Comment: @Dave yes that's what I'd like some insight on

Comment: @Dave Is there another way besides for listing 1,000 or so prime numbers and checking if it's one of them?

Comment: @nofe for most numbers you won't have to list that many, but that's the way to do it. If you'd let yourself use arrays, you could cache the primes you've already generated.

Comment: @Dave thanks, but how can I be sure that i'm covered for all integers up to 9 digits long?

Comment: @nofe The square root of `10^9` is less than 31623. Do you know how trial division works?

Comment: @nofe Re inlining, instead of writing the function and call it from the loop, write the statements you would have written in the function body in the loop, replacing the `return whatever;` with an assignment `test_result = whatever`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't really understand what you're saying. Why does it matter what the square root is? I'm not looking for prime factors, I'm looking for a sum. I don't know how to write a function that checks if a number is prime or not under the current restrictions. I've searched around online and haven't found anything inside my limitations

Comment: @nofe The square root is how far trial division needs to go. How would you write an `is_prime` function without these restrictions? And how would you use it in the Goldbach testing? First solve the problem the reasonable way, then build the solution under the given constraints from that.

Comment: @DanielFischer I can't use the square root function or power function because they are not in the stdio.h library

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9910/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-nofe)